# Convert an array of separated strings into an ValueTuple list

Tags: c#, tuples, valuetuple

I have an array of strings separated by ; , like this

```
myArr[0]="string1;string2;string3"
myArr[1]="string4;string5;string6"
```

how can i convert it into an list of ValueTuple(string,string,string)?

```
List<(string,string,string)>
```

Comment: Well, `string.Split` will convert each of those strings into an array (`string[] strArray`).  Then you'll need to create a tuple from the array (`var tuple = (strArray[0], strArray[1], strArray[2]);`.  Finally add each tuple into a `List<(string,string,string)>`.  Make sure to code defensively, a missing semi-colon will mess your code up nicely.  If you are looking for some magic LINQ statement, that's beyond my LINQ-foo, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq like this:

```
    var myArr= new string[2];
    myArr[0]="string1;string2;string3";
    myArr[1]="string4;string5;string6";
                
    var tuples = myArr.Select(x=> 
    {
       var separated = x.Split(";");
       return (separated[0],separated[1], separated[2]);
    });
                
foreach(var tuple in tuples)
{
Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.Item1}, {tuple.Item2}, {tuple.Item3}");
}
```

Comment: The OP asks specifically for `ValueTuple`. So `return Tuple.Create(x, y, z)` should be `return (x, y, z)`